# Почему вызывается деструктор

Tags: c++

Не совсем понятно почему сразу после создания объекта вызывается его деструктор.

```
IShape *shape = &Rectangle(5, 5);
```

`IShape` это базовый класс для `Rectangle`. 
Однако после серии вызовов деструкторов от `Rectangle`, `IShape` все равно получает адрес какого-то инициализированного объекта в точности как `Rectangle(5, 5)`.

Comment: Потому что это просто временный объект...

Comment: @Harry так а почему я все равно получаю адрес на инициализированный объект, если он удален?

Comment: взятие адреса у rvalue является невалидной операцией, так что вы тут получаете только ошибку компиляции

Comment: @VTT ошибки не возникает при компиляции. Компилятор MSVC

Comment: @VTT за это флаг `-fpermissive` отвечает вроде как. Может выключен по умолчанию.

Comment: https://godbolt.org/z/-RCO6X

Comment: @VTT а по какой тогда причине у меня компилируется программа?

Comment: @elvy а это так важно? в любом случае предупреждение быть должно. Причину описали по сути. Думаю версия компилятора или флаги или подобное сказываются.

Comment: Ну в vc++ действительно есть нестандартное расширение, разрешающее такую операцию. Однако использовать его не следует, а в таком примере это гарантированный фейл.

Answer (score 0):

Во-первых, если вы не реализовали какую-то свою версию перегруженного оператора `&`, этот код некомпилируем в принципе. Результатом выражения `Rectangle(5, 5)` является временный объект. В С++ запрещается применять встроенный угарный оператор `&` ко временным объектам. То есть никакого "сразу вызывается его деструктор" тут нет - код просто некорректен.

Во-вторых, как сказано выше, выражение `Rectangle(5, 5)` создает временный объект. И да, за исключением ряда специальных случаев, такой объект существует лишь до конца того выражения, которое его создало. То есть деструктор для таких объектов вызывается не "сразу", но "почти сразу". Не было бы ничего удивительного в быстром уничтожении такого объекта (если бы ваш код был корректным).

Comment: https://godbolt.org/z/SkzgxZ ну в теории собрать то можно)

Comment: @pavel: Что такое "в теории собрать"? Может еще компилятор Паскаля применить и он тоже что-то тут "скомпилирует"?

Comment: ну взять стандартный компилятор и получить исполняемый файл. А в теории значит что смысл только теоретический. Я не могу придумать ситуации когда подобное имеет смысл и не попадает под UB.

Comment: @pavel Стандартный компилятор в ответ на такой код обязан выдать требуемое стандартом диагностическое сообщение. После такого сообщения какие-либо полученные "исполняемые файлы" являются не более чем мусором, который компилятор забыл за собой убрать. Теоретически.

Comment: @AnT код компилируется и никаких перегрузок вообще не реализовано. Если warning level поставить на максимум, то выдает только предупреждение, но код компилируется. `nonstandard extension used: class rvalue used as lvalue`

Comment: @elvy: Если ваш компилятор *не выдает* никаких диагностических сообщений на этот код, то это значит, что либо ваш компилятор сломан, либо ваш компилятор не является компилятором С++ вообще. Если ваш компилятор *выдает* диагностические сообщения, то это в мире С++ называется *НЕ компилируется*.